# Voltar para pagina anterior : Electron

Tags: javascript, onclick, electron

Estou utilizando Electron para desenvolver uma aplicação onde seu objetivo é deixar alguns sites selecionados ali.

Agora estou enfrentando um problema que quando eu vou para um link de uma das opções que estão na aplicação eu não consigo voltar a pagina inicial, onde se encontra as outras opções.

Já tentei o seguinte:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
let mainWindow;
app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  mainWindow.loadURL(path.join('file://', __dirname, 'index.html'));
  setMainMenu();
});

function setMainMenu() {
  const template = [
    {
      label: 'Voltar para o Menu',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Menu Principal',
          accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+H',
          click() {
            win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1440, height: 800 })
             win.loadFile('index.html')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
}
```

Só que dessa forma ele abre um novo aplicativo e não volta para a tela inicial, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer esse botão de "voltar", no menu nativo do Electron

Exemplo com imagem:
[image: Pagina inicial]

[image: Indo para um das opções escolhidas]

[image: Quando clicado aqui, voltar para o Menu inicial]

Comment: `new BrowserWindow` vai abrir uma nova janela, se você quer continuar na mesma tela, acho que `window.location.href ="/index.html" ` talvez resolva, mas percebi que quando você abre um link, ele abre já abre uma nova janela, não seria correto apenas fecha-la?

Comment: @edsonalves adicionei tres imagens explicando o processo que acontece, não sei te dizer se fecha-la funcionaria, mas se essa for uma opção, como posso fazer ?

Comment: É mais ou menos assim, não sei sua versão mas basicamente você precisa acessar o remote e pegar a janela atual: `let w = app.remote.getCurrentWindow(); w.close()`

Comment: é realmente dessa forma não irá funcionar, ele fecha a aplicação e eu preciso voltar para a pagina inicial no caso o "index.html"

Comment: Então a outra opção deve servir

Comment: uma duvida, esse window.location.href = "/index.html"  deve ir no arquivo main.js certo?

Comment: No click,  no mesmo lugar onde vc já tenta ir pro index

Comment: Talvez seja correto `let w = app.remote.getCurrentWindow(); w.location.href ="index.html"`

Comment: é engraçado que ele da um erro "Cannot read property getCurrentWindow of undefined", parece que ele não sabe onde está a pagina que deve ser fechada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88302/discussion-between-edson-alves-and-brenda-xavier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
click(){
 mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}
```